# Allow user to seturl in Webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I having trouble improving my webview. I want there to be a page once the app opens were the user can set the url that the webview is permanently going to. It sounds very simple but I'm having a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

mb you can first show dialog, where user should enter url, and this url set to web view

or start another activity, when user enter url

Comment: yeah this is exactly what im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Create UrlActivity.java, where in onCreate you will do following thing.

take URL to be shown as a user input in `EditText`.

while firing intent to next activity, set that URL in intent's putExtra.
get this extra string in next activity using

```
String url = getIntent.getStringExtra("key of your urlstring");
```

and load this url in your webView.